# Can you use a dynamic variable created from a string using Python, Flask, and Jinja2 when including a file?

Tags: python, flask, variables, dynamic, jinja2

I have a Wrapper class that contains other wrappers in a list. It holds a file name, a param name. I have two other classes. That inherit from the wrapper class and adds some stuff pertaining to that wrapper.

```
class Wrapper(list):
    def __init__(self, FileName='', ParamName=''):
        super().__init__()
        self.FileName=FileName
        self.ParamName = ParamName

class ContentA(Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, AWrapper):
        super().__init__('ContentA.html', 'MainContent')
        self.append(AWrapper)
    
    

class ContentB(Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, SomeContent = '')
        super()__init__('ContentB.html', 'SubContent')
        self.Content = SomeContent


contB = ContentB('Hello Guys')
contA = ContentA(contB)

return render_template('index.html', ContA=contA)
```

Then in jinja I'm trying to grab the Parameter Name from the classB to include it within the included html file.

```
<!-----------------index.html------------------>
{% for cont in ContA %}
{% with cont.ParamName=cont %}
{% include cont.FileName %}
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}

<-----------------ContentB.html---------------->
<p> {{ SubContent.Content }} </p>
```

Anyway to change the variable name itself from a string contained in a subclass?

Basically tried the above, then did a lot of research and found most saying it's impossible. I have considered just making the variable/ParamName the same from file to file, but I would like different names for debugging purposes.

Comment: If you need name dict is the structure in most cases. You really don't want to define variable names from strings supplied from files / API responses / user input and so on. It is doable with a combination of f-strings, `eval` and walrus operator, but I'm not writing another answer which will get down vote literally 1 second after posting, because someone wants to shout "It is a b4d pract1ce !oneone111!". I know it is...xD

Comment: Ill look into eval and walrus, I havn't heard of those. I'm ok with bad 4 practice. This is a personal project, not something going into production. Also, everyone says it, but never gives great examples as to why. With this setup I can use whatever paramname I want when creating a jinja template then define it in whatever wrapper component is made. Right now, Every file at every level must have the same ParamName, but not all wrappers are on the same level.